Displaying '123' when doing print $t{'123'} while %t is undefined
I have a large language file with the following structure:
  Click here|Cliquez ici
  New|Nouveau
  ...

Then I have an application in English and French. The language file is loaded by CONF.pm into hash %t, which is used like this throughout the application:
  <input type="button" value="$t{'Click here'}">
  <a href="new.pl">$t{'New'}</a>
  ...

So, depending on the user setting, the application is displayed in English or French. For this, the large language file must first be loaded by CONF.pm in order to fill %t.
The problem is that most of our users are English, and we loose quite some memory by loading the language file every time. The language file is not "really" necessary for an English user, because the value of $t{'Click here'} will always be Click here.
You will agree that this is probably not the most intelligent language config design. Does Perl have a possibility to NOT load the languae file, when the user is English ? Just display the key of the hash, when the value is undefined ?
  <input type="button" value="Click here">
  <a href="new.pl">New</a>

I can't go change all the $t{'...'} in the application files, there must be many thousands. Not loading the large language file for every single request would save me a good deal of memory.

What does your code that handles %t look like? I.e. are the keys mentioned in code, or just in the html?

If you do not have the keys in your code until you load the language file, there is no way to access them before that.

my %t; my $loaded_langfile = "Click here|Cliquez ici\nNew|Nouveau"; for ( split /\n/, $loaded_langfile ) { my ( $key, $value ) = split /\|/; $t{$key} = $value; }

So you only have 2 keys in your code. The rest are in the html? If you want the English keys, you need to have them in your code. Which I take it from your very brief reply means that you'd need to read them from a file. Which is what you are trying not to do. It may be that Barney's suggestion about Tie::Hash::Identify is your best bet.

I find it difficult to believe you have so many translations that the memory cost is at all significant.  what problems are being caused by this?

Large is relative, the language file is 250KB. You're right of course that this doesn't sound very disastrous. But all depends on the number of simultaneous users/requests, especially during peak moments. I'm not seeing anything urgent indeed, but I believe this kind of exercises are Good Practice, and every bit helps to save memory. Isn't forecasting evil an important part of our job :)

@BartVanderDonck It may also be premature optimization that leads to a larger resource drain than reading a 250kb file. :) For example, the suggested solution might lead to you loading an even larger file, and several other files. And each usage of the hash might require something that summed up will be larger than reading that file. :) But it's hard to say, of course, since we have no information about your code.

I think that this can be done with tied hashes. So when the language is English then you could set the hash %tto be a hash tied to Tie::Hash::Identity. In that case the value returned for the key would be the key itself. For French you would still import the whole mapping.

A Tie::Hash::Identity hash doesn't support exists (but a simple patch would fix that).

Variable::Magic also presents a simple (and I suspect slightly faster) solution: my $wiz = wizard op_info => VMG_UVAR, fetch => sub { "$_[2]" }, exists => sub { 1 }; cast %t, $wiz;. (Tying is a special form of magic, but generic magic is sufficient here.)
